# How often am I allowed to contact PayPal API?

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, production-environment

Right now I contact the PayPal API to check the subscription status everytime the user enters the `profile settings`, and each time a new `access token` is generated.

Is this considered a bad practice in production? Should I rather set a timer for 24 hours and check the subscription status only once a day to reduce the load on PayPal's end? Does this even matter?

And would it be better to somehow store a new `access token` in the `.env` everytime it expires (PayPal gives the duration)?

I just want to know if there are any limitations since [https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/rate-limiting/][1]
does not give any specific numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for PayPal's support but something like 100 requests/minute per endpoint would seem safe. Caching the access token is always preferred, certainly--saves you an unnecessary API call.